# Creating Alexa Skill Notifications (like quotemaker)

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I need help in sending notifications to alexa device of a user (echo, dot, etc.. not the other non amazon alexa devices) from alexa skill i am building. I see quote maker doing it but, how its doing it is a blackbox.

For example if the user ordered some item through my skill (say abc org). I would like to notify user on their alexa devices about the status of order proactively ( eg, item shipped, or item out for deliver today).

Amazon has this already for amazon shopping, but i dont see much information on implementing the same for skills.

I saw quote maker creating a notification for self, but how its doing it is a blackbox

Comment: Notification in Alexa Skill is still in developer preview. https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/833b9af4-26e6-47d2-a13d-bdbd9a257512/expanded-developer-preview-of-notifications-for-alexa-skills

Comment: @bgsuello are we able to use this yet? If so how?

Comment: @Caltor i'm not sure, i think it's not yet available on general public.

Comment: @bgsuello hmmm ok thanks. It seems to have disappeared into a black hole. I can't see a beta programme or general release for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question and am still not 100% sure about the answer.

As best as I can tell, the Notifications API never made it out of developer preview, and instead has been replaced with the [Proactive Events API](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html#migrate-from-the-notifications-api).

Unfortunately, unless your skill needs to send notifications about trash pickup or sports scores, you're probably out of luck. [Here is the complete list of all notifications types that are currently supported:](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/schemas-for-proactive-events.html#event-catalog)

- Weather alert
- Sports event update
- Message reminder
- Order status update
- Reservation confirmation
- Trash collection reminder
- Media content availability notification
- Social game invitation notification

Comment: Is this feature still not released?
@Nathan Friend